# B(+)Tree internal structure

Tags: data-structures

I have a rough understanding of the overall high-level workings of b-trees, but something that people always seem to gloss over is the inner workings of each node.

My current understanding is that each node consists of an array of keys and an array of pointers (pointing either to another node or to the relevant data). But how do you perform insertions on a sorted array efficiently. Wouldn't it be O(n) (n as the size of the array, not the elements in the whole tree) to shuffle elements up or down every time you insert/delete a key?

Comment: You're right. For example, SQL Server performs an insertion sort when inserting a row into a page. But it does not have to move row data. Instead, it moves small 2-byte per row pointers to the actual row data.

Comment: @usr do you have a link to more details on this implmementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The familiar "it takes O(n) to insert into a sorted array" comes from the case where `n` refers to the size of the array.

In a B(+/*/you name it) tree, the nodes are arrays of *constant size*, namely the branching factor. (a node may also be partially filled, but that doesn't change anything here)

And if your array is only O(1) long, it's hard to get a factor of `n` out of thin air, so inserting into it (and various other operations) are O(1).

Comment: I'm aware the n refers to the size of the array, but my point is that n (as the size of the array in each node) is supposed to be (reasonably) big in b+trees isn't it, because of the idea of matching node size to block size of storage? This makes it less trivial, doesnt it?

Comment: @overclockwise well my point was that `n` *isn't* the size of the array here. The array in a node can never get bigger than some constant, because when you would exceed it, you split the node.

Comment: @overclockwise an other way of putting it is that insertion etc are still O(n), however you have (confusingly) defined `n` to be a constant. So it looks linear in something, but linear in a constant is just a constant again.

Comment: True, asymptotically, its constant, but it means that naive implementation's performance degrade proportional to the square of the branching factor(-1). I was wondering if there is some way to design around this if i already knew I wanted a very high branching factor.

Comment: @overclockwise store the rows inside of a page in a sorted data structure like a heap or a tree.

Comment: @usr wouldn't that negate the benefit of the high branching factor - in this case trying to minimise random access to the underlying storage. Would using a tree inside each btreenode vastly increase the number of pointer-following operations?

Comment: @overclockwise you load the whole page from disk. The internal tree is in-memory making it fast. B-trees are mainly used to make IO more efficient. And using an in-memory tree is certainly faster than using insertion sort in the asymptotic case.